# Composition in REST and consistence of the inserted data

Tags: json, rest

How to properly design REST if you have a composition? I have a `TestResult` entity, which has `TestCaseResults` entities. Both support full set of REST methods. The important fact about this (which I believe differs from many examples I found on a web) is that `TestResult` is not consistent if it doesn't have all of `TestCaseResults` How do I properly design this in REST?

1. Let's say I create it as separate but dependent resources: `api\testresults\` and `api\testresults\1\testcaseresults`. When the client wants to create a test result, he needs to `POST` to `api\testresults`, then retrieve URL `api\testresults\1\testcaseresutls` by a link from the response, and `POST` all of test case results to it. This means that at some point in time the test result is not consistent until the user finishes its operation. Basically, there is no concept of the transaction here.
2. Let's say I create only `api\testresults` resource, and embed an array of test case results inside, like this:

```
    { 
      "Name": "Test A"
      "Results": [ 
         {
           "Measured": "BB",
           ...
         },
         ...
      ]
      ...
    }
```

Then it is easier to insert, but it still hard to work with. Simple `GET` to `api\testresults\1\` will retrieve test result with a big amount of test case results. `GET` to `api\testresults\` will retrieve much more! The structure of this becomes complex. Furthermore, in the real word I have a few entities like `TestCaseResults` belong to `TestResults`, so there will be a few arrays, and each could have 100-200 elements.

3. I could try to combine the approaches. Embed the array, but also provide links to `api\testresults\1\testcaseresults` and support operations there as well. Maybe on `GET api\testresults\1\` I could provide `TestResult` without it's `TestCaseResults` but only with a link pointing to a resource, but on `POST` I could accept an array of `TestCaseResults` embedded (not sure though it is allowed to have different return types for `POST` and `GET` in REST) But now there are two approaches for inserting information, it is confusing and I'm still not sure it solves anything.

Comment: What do you use for the data store. Database? What kind?

Comment: @VictorOlex It is NHIbernate and EF in some cases. The database behind varies - we have many set ups with differents DBs. Web Api is not public

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your approach with `api\testresults\1` and `api\testresults\1\testcaseresults` seems promising.
As JSON does not have a fixed structure, you can add query parameters to your URL to control if results are inserted or not.

`api\testresults\1?with_results=true` would mean that your caller want to see the  test cases in addition to the test results.
`api\testresults\1\testcaseresults` would still return the test case results for your test *1*.

If you fear that the number of test case results is too large, you can add pagination parameters, that would be reuse in the testcaseresults call.
`api\testresults\1?with_results=true&per_page=10` would include the only the 10 first results. To get more, use `api\testresults\1\testcaseresults?per_page=10&page=2` and so on, as it is the dedicated endpoint.

Cheers

Note: if you want a flexible API still returning JSON data, you can give a look to [GraphQL](http://graphql.org/learn/), the trendy approach.